# Battery drains out in 24 mins (Ubuntu 14.04 on Lenovo Thinkpad x201i)

Tags: 14.04, power-management, battery, thinkpad

Hardinfo Extract | Battery

-Battery: BAT0-
State       : charging (load: 186 mA)
Capacity        : 610 mAh / 5600 mAh (10.89%)
Battery Technology      : rechargeable (LION)
Model Number        : 42T4837
Serial Number       : 32589

### ----------

### After installing TLP, the battery backup almost doubled to 46 minutes. (Still lower than the windows comparable of 3-4 hours). After 10 minutes though, the status says 22 minutes - i.e. draining faster than it says. Here's the tlp-stat output (while on battery backup)

TLP Output  - sudo tlp-stat -s -b
--- TLP 0.8 --------------------------------------------

+++ System Info
System         = LENOVO ThinkPad X201 3626MQ9

BIOS           = 6QET61WW (1.31 )

Release        = Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS

Kernel         = 3.13.0-67-generic #110-Ubuntu SMP Fri Oct 23 13:24:41 UTC 2015 x86_64

/proc/cmdline  = BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-67-generic root=UUID=c2854d68-9d9b-4fed-beaf-4bb9369aa5ba ro quiet splash vt.handoff=7

Init system    = upstart

+++ System Status
TLP power save = enabled

power source   = battery

+++ ThinkPad Extended Battery Functions

tp-smapi   = active

tpacpi-bat = inactive (unsupported hardware)

+++ ThinkPad Battery Status: BAT0 (Main / Internal)

/sys/devices/platform/smapi/BAT0/manufacturer               = LGC

/sys/devices/platform/smapi/BAT0/model                      = 42T4837

/sys/devices/platform/smapi/BAT0/manufacture_date           = 2010-12-02

/sys/devices/platform/smapi/BAT0/first_use_date             = 2011-08-27

/sys/devices/platform/smapi/BAT0/cycle_count                =    110

/sys/devices/platform/smapi/BAT0/design_capacity            =  62160 [mWh]

/sys/devices/platform/smapi/BAT0/last_full_capacity         =   6820 [mWh]

/sys/devices/platform/smapi/BAT0/remaining_capacity         =   6590 [mWh]

/sys/devices/platform/smapi/BAT0/remaining_percent          =     97 [%]

/sys/devices/platform/smapi/BAT0/remaining_running_time_now =     46 [min]

/sys/devices/platform/smapi/BAT0/remaining_charging_time    = not_charging [min]

/sys/devices/platform/smapi/BAT0/power_now                  =  -8529 [mW]

/sys/devices/platform/smapi/BAT0/power_avg                  =  -9709 [mW]

/sys/devices/platform/smapi/BAT0/state                      = discharging

/sys/devices/platform/smapi/BAT0/start_charge_thresh        =     96 [%]

/sys/devices/platform/smapi/BAT0/stop_charge_thresh         =    100 [%]

/sys/devices/platform/smapi/BAT0/force_discharge            =      0

Comment: You need a new Battery its that simple there is nothing you can do on any operating system that will fix a broken battery. this is an off topic question

Comment: Thanks Neil. The laptop worked fine before the migration from Windows. Windows provided a power back up of 3-4 hours.

Comment: Install [TLP](http://linrunner.de/en/tlp/docs/tlp-linux-advanced-power-management.html#installation) and show the output of `tlp-stat -s -b`(edit your post)

Comment: My X220 with original battery still gives me 6 hours of battery. Have you checked your CPU use with system monitor?

Comment: The battery is old and its full charge threshold shows its time to replace, the X201 is older than my 220 and will need a battery change.

Comment: Thanks Arup. How do I check CPU use with system monitor? (It is difficult to understand why the same battery should provide a 3-4 hours of backup with Windows)

Answer (score 0):

Your battery is 5 years old and worn down to 10% capacity:

```
design_capacity    = 62160 [mWh]
last_full_capacity =  6820 [mWh]
```

This battery won't run 3-4 hours with Windows. Definitely.

You may try to [recalibrate](http://linrunner.de/en/tlp/docs/tlp-linux-advanced-power-management.html#recalibrate) but i doubt this will help much.

I suggest to replace the battery.

Comment: Thanks linrunner, Arup and Neil. Will try a new battery and post an update here either way. Cheers

Comment: Update: New battery provides a decent backup of 3-4 hours. Thanks guys!